# Search script not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

the search.php page is just not fetching results. as soon as i press on submit i get a blank page no matter what string i put in.
cant understand why!
Please help

the form is working fine, but somehow on submitting it gives me a blank page, instead of the results, where m i going wrong?

```
form code

<form name="form" action="../search.php" method="get"> 
        <input name="q" type="text" value="type!" onfocus="this.value=''" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>


php code

  <?php

 // Get the search variable from URL
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $var = $_GET['q'] ;
 $trimmed = trim($var);//trim whitespace from the stored variable

// rows to return


// check for an empty string and display a message.
 if ($trimmed=="")
 {
  echo "<p>Please enter a search...</p>";
 exit;
 }

// check for a search parameter
if (!isset($var))
  {
  echo "<p>We dont seem to have a search parameter!</p>";
  exit;
  }

   //connect to database
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost","",""); //(host, username, password)

  //specify database 
  mysql_select_db("test",$con) or die("Unable to select database"); //select which database we're using

 // Build SQL Query  
 $query = "select * from questions where question like \"%$trimmed%\"  or detail like \"%   $trimmed%\"     or name like \"%$trimmed%\"
 order by name"; // EDIT HERE and specify your table and field names for the SQL query

 $numresults=mysql_query($query);
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);

// If we have no results, offer a google search as an alternative

if ($numrows == 0)
  {
 echo "<h4>Results</h4>";
 echo "<p>Sorry, your search: &quot;" . $trimmed . "&quot; returned zero results</p>";

// google
 echo "<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q=" 
 . $trimmed . "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Look up 
 " . $trimmed . " on Google\">Click here</a> to try the 
 search on google</p>";
 }

// next determine if s has been passed to script, if not use 0
 if (empty($s)) {
 $s=0;
 }

   // get results
   $query =  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE question LIKE '%$q%' OR name LIKE '%$q%' or detail like '%$q%'";  
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");

    // display what the person searched for
     echo "<p>You searched for: &quot;" . $var . "&quot;</p>";

    // begin to show results set
   echo "Results";
   $count = 1 + $s ;

 // display the results returned
  while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<table  align=center class=lims>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th bgcolor=#5D9BCC >QUESTIONS</th>";
  echo "<td bgcolor=#FEE9A9>" . $row['question'] . "</td>";


  echo "<tr>";



  echo "<th bgcolor=#5D9BCC>Alias</th>";
  echo "<td bgcolor=#FEE9A9>" . $row['detail'] . "</td>";

 echo "</tr>";

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th bgcolor=#5D9BCC>Code</th>";
 echo "<td bgcolor=#FEE9A9>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 $title = $row["name"];

 echo "$count.)&nbsp;$title" ;
 $count++ ;
 }

  $currPage = (($s/10) + 1);

  //break before paging
   echo "<br />";

  // next we need to do the links to other results
  if ($s>=1) { // bypass PREV link if s is 0
  $prevs=($s-$limit);
  print "&nbsp;<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$prevs&q=$var\">&lt;&lt; 
  Prev 10</a>&nbsp&nbsp;";
  }

  // calculate number of pages needing links
  $pages=intval($numrows/10);

 // $pages now contains int of pages needed unless there is a remainder from division

 if ($numrows%10) {
 // has remainder so add one page
 $pages++;
 }

  // check to see if last page
  if (!((($s+$limit)/10)==$pages) && $pages!=1) {

  // not last page so give NEXT link
  $news=$s+10;

  echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$news&q=$var\">Next 10 &gt;&gt;</a>";
  }

  $a = $s + (10) ;
  if ($a > $numrows) { $a = $numrows ; }
   $b = $s + 1 ;
  echo "<p>Showing results $b to $a of $numrows</p>";
  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: the database fields are 'id' 'name' 'question' 'detail'

Comment: That's pretty loaded with injections of any kind. Also, a modernization of the html wouldn't hurt

Comment: @damien: what is meant by the moderization of html, can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for `Submit` in `$_POST`, but the method specified in the form is `GET`.

To have it work, change the PHP code to look for `$_GET['Submit']`.

(But I'd move instead everything, form method included, to `POST`).

That said, your script seems to have been pasted twice, the second version using `$q` instead of `$trimmed` (is `$q` defined?), and a SQL table called 'table' instead of 'questions':

```
// get results
$query =  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE question LIKE '%$q%' OR name LIKE '%$q%' or detail like '%$q%'";  
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked after replacing OST with GET and yeah q wasn't defined, so changed it to trimmed.

Comment: I'd like to know one more thing, sorry if i am bothering you. But what if i want to display the results on the same page?

Comment: In the same page of the search form? That is quite a bit more complicated. You'd need to use AJAX; the form button submits an AJAX query, but the page isn't reloaded; instead, some DIV in the HTML gets its contents replaced with the result of a "hidden" call to the search PHP script. You'd need to get a good AJAX tutorial for that, though.

Comment: Another method, although arguably not as neat, would be to generate the form in the same PHP file that shows the results (similar to the code in your example, assuming it's all in one file). Then the user would see the form, followed by the results.

Answer (score 0):

POST keys are case sensitive.  It needs to be `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))`

EDIT: Nevermind above answer.  The problem is the form method is GET and you're trying to access the submit key using $_POST.  You need to change it to `$_GET['Submit']`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the data from the search input exists? (reformulated by comment request :-))

```
// Get the search variable from URL
if(isset($_GET['q']))
```

instead of

```
// Get the search variable from URL
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: That's not "validating", though, just a check

Comment: Of course, I don't know what his business rules are! :) He might need extra validation! But at least he'll know the variable exists. ;-) EDIT: Oh boy, I hadn't read past the first `if` to be honest... Please god help him..